# How download an image from browser in a single click using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

My code:

```
<div>
    <a href="/images/test-201.gif" class="download">Download</a>
</div>
```

I need to do is when I click on the Download. It should open a new window like save as for this image. I need to do this using HTML or javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: You can modify headers sent by your server for this specific file.

Comment: @3nigma : No it is not. I am talking about to download image not any file(pdf or zip)

Answer (score 3):

In short: you cannot achieve this using javascript and html only.

Without a server-side language (like php) you won't be able to force a file download. The server needs to send the image to the client along with the right response headers

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's not posible. 
You have to POST it to the backend (server) and response it back from server using the header `Content-disposition: attachment`.

Also this wont work as an `AJAX` response so you have to do something like

```
document.location = 'download_image.php?file=test-201.gif';
```

which response the download with the correct header as mentioned above.

As far as I know this is the only cross-browser solution to trigger downloads via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an attribute known as download. Just add the attribute download="test image" to your anchor tag. "test image" can be any name you want to give to the image. Here is the syntax :

```
<a href="/images/test-201.gif" class="download" download="test image">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using javascript only.

Without a server-side language (like php) you won't be able to do this. The server needs to send the image to the client.